# Spaceless response based on Symfony2 environment

Tags: symfony, twig

What I am looking is the way to enable/disable `{% spaceless %}{% endspaceless %}` wrapper for the whole `Response` object based on current Symfony environment. I think I should listen to `kernel.view` event and modify response there, but I can't make it.

The reason for this is that it is better to debug with all those spaces, but keep it minified for production usage.

Has anybody done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spaceless` is a Twig tag, the response will never know about it.

You can't easily disable it as it's part of the `Twig_Extension_Core` and there is no option to disable it.

You have to find another way.
Maybe directly from your template (using it or not the depending on the environnement).

Answer (score 0):

Implement a ResponseListener in your bundle:

```
class ResponseListener
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // Compress HTML on prod environment only
        if($this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() == 'prod')
            $event->getResponse()->setContent(trim(preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $event->getResponse()->getContent())));
    }
}
```

Then declare in services.yml:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.response_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\ResponseListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
        arguments: [@service_container]
```